# Gurobi add constraint which two variables cant be zero at the same time

Tags: gurobi, logical-constraints

I'm currently using Gurobi in python and trying to add a constraint that the variable will not equal to 0 at the same time, say `a != 0 or b != 0`, both a and b can be negative or positive. But I can't find a proper way to add this constraint. Does anyone have idea about this?

Edit: The problem I'm trying to solve is to find the proper plane that has the smallest distances in summation for a list of points. The equation I used is $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{|Ax_{i} + By_{i} + Cz_{i} + D|}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2 + C^2}}$ where $x_{i}, y_{i}, z_{i}$ refer to the point, A,B,C,D refer to the plane equation Ax + By + Cz + D = 0, and thus A,B,C cant be 0 at the same time.

Comment: Can you post your mathematical equation that you have tried to cater above requirement?

Comment: Hi, I just edited my post with the equation, do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Are the decision variables $a$ and $b$ continuous or binary?

Comment: A small denominator yields a bad objective value, so you might not need to explicitly impose constraints to avoid it.  What happens when you try to solve the unconstrained problem?

Comment: they are continuous. And when I apply with no constraints, the value of A,B,C,D are just stuck at 0, and each point put into the equation has the result 0.

Comment: Try specifying a nonzero initial solution.  Alternatively, impose a quadratic constraint $A^2+B^2+C^2 \ge \epsilon$ for some small constant $\epsilon>0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a trick I sometimes use in situations like this. First, you need to confirm that for any optimal solution $(A, B, C, D)$ and any scalar $\lambda \neq 0$, $\lambda\cdot (A, B, C, D)$ is also optimal. It obviously selects the same plane, so chances are good this will hold.

Assuming it does, generate a random vector $\alpha$ distributed uniformly over $[-1, 1]^3$ and add the constraint $\alpha_1 A + \alpha_2 B + \alpha_3 C = 1$ to the model. This obviously rules out $A = B = C = 0$. For any optimal $(A, B, C)$ for which the left side is not zero, we can by assumption multiply by a constant to get another optimal solution that sums to 1. So the only potential issue is whether the optimal solution might have inner product 0 with $\alpha$. Since we chose $\alpha$ using a continuous distribution over a region with positive volume, that has probability zero of occurring. So unless you are living under a curse, this ought to work.